# On mouse wheel scrolling, window doesn't move unless specific function has performed

Tags: jquery, scroll

I want to achieve this:

When user starts scrolling the mouse wheel, a specific function whould be executed while window stays still. Window starts moving after function is completed.

Something like this: http://getcirulis.com/

Comment: I found this plugin: http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/

Comment: Yes it is solved, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved with http://johnpolacek.github.com/superscrollorama/ plugin